# Post links to Social Networking Sites directly from website's admin panel

Tags: php, jquery, web, share, social-networking

I've developed an e-commerce website in php. There is an admin panel with all product list and respective links on website.

I want to put options to share the product's link on various social networking websites.

```
facebook, twitter, linkedin, google+, for example.
```

A separate button for each website would be put along with product name.
*Is there any solution to post product's links directly from website's admin panel ?*

Comment: Look into there API documents everything is available that you need.

Comment: I thought it first. But I wonder if there any bundled framework available to do this task at once.

Comment: StackOverflow policy prohibits asking for recommendations...